# Transmission not downloading - can't connect to trackers

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, mybook

I've got Transmission 2.82 installed on my NAS drive (MyBookLive) and it has been working great for over a year now.

I moved (physical locations) and now none of the torrents will download. When I look at the individual torrent info I get an error "Announce error: Connection failed"

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Again - I have simple done nothing but pack up all my stuff and move to a different locale...

This is my current settings file

```
{
    "alt-speed-down": 50,
    "alt-speed-enabled": false,
    "alt-speed-time-begin": 540,
    "alt-speed-time-day": 127,
    "alt-speed-time-enabled": false,
    "alt-speed-time-end": 1020,
    "alt-speed-up": 50,
    "bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
    "bind-address-ipv6": "::",
    "blocklist-enabled": true,
    "blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist",
    "cache-size-mb": 4,
    "dht-enabled": true,
    "download-dir": "/shares/Public/WWW/TR-Downloads",
    "download-queue-enabled": true,
    "download-queue-size": 5,
    "encryption": 1,
    "idle-seeding-limit": 30,
    "idle-seeding-limit-enabled": false,
    "incomplete-dir": "/root/Downloads",
    "incomplete-dir-enabled": false,
    "lpd-enabled": false,
    "message-level": 1,
    "peer-congestion-algorithm": "",
    "peer-id-ttl-hours": 6,
    "peer-limit-global": 200,
    "peer-limit-per-torrent": 50,
    "peer-port": 49405,
    "peer-port-random-high": 65535,
    "peer-port-random-low": 49152,
    "peer-port-random-on-start": true,
    "peer-socket-tos": "default",
    "pex-enabled": true,
    "port-forwarding-enabled": true,
    "preallocation": 1,
    "prefetch-enabled": 1,
    "queue-stalled-enabled": true,
    "queue-stalled-minutes": 30,
    "ratio-limit": 2,
    "ratio-limit-enabled": false,
    "rename-partial-files": true,
    "rpc-authentication-required": false,
    "rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0",
    "rpc-enabled": true,
    "rpc-password": "{6993306827d95b964764ab2c3ce1435fb7fc1f92JKI04/uW",
    "rpc-port": 9091,
    "rpc-url": "/transmission/",
    "rpc-username": "",
    "rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1",
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,
    "scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true,
    "script-torrent-done-enabled": false,
    "script-torrent-done-filename": "",
    "seed-queue-enabled": false,
    "seed-queue-size": 10,
    "speed-limit-down": 100,
    "speed-limit-down-enabled": false,
    "speed-limit-up": 0,
    "speed-limit-up-enabled": true,
    "start-added-torrents": true,
    "trash-original-torrent-files": false,
    "umask": 0,
    "upload-slots-per-torrent": 14,
    "utp-enabled": true,
    "watch-dir": "/DataVolume/shares/Public/torrents",
    "watch-dir-enabled": true
}
```

I've just setup logging and here's what I get back when starting a torrent

```
[04:27:08.560] UDP Failed to set receive buffer: requested 4194304, got 65534 (tr-udp.c:78)
[04:27:08.560] UDP Failed to set send buffer: requested 1048576, got 65534 (tr-udp.c:89)
```

Comment: Do you still have the same router you had at the old location? have you changed ISPs? did your new ISP connection assign you a Modem, or a Router? In your Transmission config, are you using a static port for incoming connections, or using UPNP to open a port?

Comment: edit - hitting enter caused me to post early

Same router - same ISP - I am downloading a torrent on my macbook right now and it works just fine... so ISP might not be issue?

I am using a static port - I believe it's closed (and the default port) but again that hadn't been changed before either, so it was probably closed back at the old place